# Smart contract function works in Remix but not in webapp or etherscan

Tags: web3js, remix, etherscan

I have a smart contract with a function that returns the correct value when running the function calls directly from remix. However when I try to call the function in a web app or from ether scan I get this error:

```
[ getTotalClaimable method Response ]
    uint256 :  Error: Returned error: execution reverted: ERC721: balance query for the zero address
```

And this is an example of the data from remix:

```
0:
uint256: 165591333333333333333322
```

The function I am trying to call is getTotalClaimable

Here is the code for my contract:

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at polygonscan.com on 2022-04-09
*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

// File: @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (token/ERC20/IERC20.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @dev Interface of the ERC20 standard as defined in the EIP.
 */
interface IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
     * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
     * zero by default.
     *
     * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
     * another (`to`).
     *
     * Note that `value` may be zero.
     */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

// File: @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol


// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (utils/Context.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @dev Provides information about the current execution context, including the
 * sender of the transaction and its data. While these are generally available
 * via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct
 * manner, since when dealing with meta-transactions the account sending and
 * paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application
 * is concerned).
 *
 * This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.
 */
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}

// File: @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol


// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (access/Ownable.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


/**
 * @dev Contract module which provides a basic access control mechanism, where
 * there is an account (an owner) that can be granted exclusive access to
 * specific functions.
 *
 * By default, the owner account will be the one that deploys the contract. This
 * can later be changed with {transferOwnership}.
 *
 * This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the modifier
 * `onlyOwner`, which can be applied to your functions to restrict their use to
 * the owner.
 */
abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor() {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
     * `onlyOwner` functions anymore. Can only be called by the current owner.
     *
     * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
     * thereby removing any functionality that is only available to the owner.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Can only be called by the current owner.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Internal function without access restriction.
     */
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


interface iMetaSpeciesV1 {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns(uint256);
    function walletOfOwner(address owner) external view returns(uint256[] memory);
}

interface iSpeciesCoin is IERC20{
    function mint(address user, uint256 amount) external;
}

contract SPCCWrapper is Ownable{

    iMetaSpeciesV1 public MetaSpeciesV1;
    iSpeciesCoin public SpeciesToken;

    uint256 constant public BASE_RATE = 20 ether;

    bool public rewardPaused = true;

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public lastUpdate;

    constructor(address MetaSpeciesAddress, address SPCCAddress) {
        MetaSpeciesV1 = iMetaSpeciesV1(MetaSpeciesAddress);
        SpeciesToken = iSpeciesCoin(SPCCAddress);
    }

    function claimReward() external {
        require(!rewardPaused, "Claiming reward has been paused"); 

        uint256 ownerTokenCount = MetaSpeciesV1.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        uint256[] memory claimTokens = MetaSpeciesV1.walletOfOwner(msg.sender);

        for(uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            if(lastUpdate[claimTokens[i]] == 0) {
                lastUpdate[claimTokens[i]] = block.timestamp;
            }
            SpeciesToken.mint(msg.sender, getPendingReward(claimTokens[i]));
            lastUpdate[claimTokens[i]] = block.timestamp;
        }
    }




    function getPendingReward(uint256 user) internal view returns(uint256) {
        return BASE_RATE * (block.timestamp - lastUpdate[user]) / 60;
    }


    function getTotalClaimable(address user) external view returns(uint256) {

        uint256 ownerTokenCount = MetaSpeciesV1.balanceOf(user);
        uint256[] memory claimTokens = MetaSpeciesV1.walletOfOwner(msg.sender);
        uint256 count = 0;

        for(uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            if(lastUpdate[claimTokens[i]] != 0){
                count += getPendingReward(claimTokens[i]);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }



    

    function toggleReward() public onlyOwner {
        rewardPaused = !rewardPaused;
    }


    function setContractAddress(address _address) public onlyOwner {
        MetaSpeciesV1 = iMetaSpeciesV1(_address);
    }    


    function setSpeciesTokenContractAddress(address _address) public onlyOwner {
        SpeciesToken = iSpeciesCoin(_address);
    }    
}
```

Any ideas why I get different data in remix?

Comment: If remix and etherscan are returning different result means you are interacting with different contracts on etherscan and remix. Smart contracts are deterministic so they'll return same result.  It could be either different contract adress, or diff network. You maybe on local blockchain with remix and other chain on etherscan

Comment: If you have verified that all values are same and you are interacting with same contract. Add contract address on etherscan payload. I'll check

Comment: It is the same contract on both platforms

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x4c5f1A976e29Bfc260a3082E49DeEe4d8b8A66fD

Comment: Looking at error message: "ERC721: balance query for the zero address", looks likeetherscan/ webapp, do not have access to your metamask  wallet (or any wallet). Can u check if you can any function of any other contract to rule out if contract is at fault or just wallet connection?

Comment: Every other function on that contract works in remix and polygonscan. There must be a difference between the way remix sends the function to the contract compared to polygonscan.

`function getTotalClaimable(address user) external view returns(uint256)` 

The above function should only need this passed correct?

`await newSpccContract.methods.getTotalClaimable(account).call();`